# What is the ideal Grails class domain for this tree structure

Tags: grails, tree-structure

I'm developing a website that need categories with sub categories.

My current domain class is:

```
package com.abc

class Category {

    String title
    String description
    Category parent

    static hasMany = [children: Category, listing: Listing]

    static constraints = {
        title blank: false
        description blank: true
    } 
}
```

But it gives me an error:

> Property [children] in class [class com.abc.Category] is a
>   bidirectional one-to-many with two possible properties on the inverse
>   side. Either name one of the properties on other side of the
>   relationship [category] or use the 'mappedBy' static to define the
>   property that the relationship is mapped with. Example: static
>   mappedBy = [children:'myprop']

Comment: So what is the question? see how to use mappedby http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html and configure properly. Also you need relation either  to parent or to children as usual

Answer (score 4):

I would use only `Category parent`. We can always get children by `Category.findAllByParent`. This is also the easiest solution to use later on in tree creation.